# How do I consider subclass relationships in SPARQL using Apache Jena?

Tags: java, sparql, jena, ontology

I would like to add a new subclass to an existing ontology. With the following JAVA Code using Apache Jena and ru.avicomp.ontapi I can already load the ontology and manipulate data.

```java
import java.io.File;

import org.apache.jena.update.UpdateAction;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyCreationException;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyStorageException;

import ru.avicomp.ontapi.OntManagers;
import ru.avicomp.ontapi.OntologyManager;
import ru.avicomp.ontapi.OntologyModel;
import ru.avicomp.ontapi.jena.model.OntGraphModel;

public class OntologyManipulator {

    OntGraphModel _base;
    private OntologyManager manager;
    private OntologyModel _ontology;

    private String _uri = "http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/2.0.0";
    String _ns = _uri+"#";
    String _prefixRDF = "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#";
    String _prefixEX = _ns;

    public OntologyManipulator() {

    }

    // reads the ontology into jena
    public void loadOntology(String path) {
        manager = OntManagers.createONT();
        try {
            _ontology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(new File(path));

            _base = _ontology.asGraphModel();

        } catch (OWLOntologyCreationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void execSPARQLquery(String _query) {
        UpdateAction.parseExecute(_query, _base);

        _ontology.axioms().forEach(System.out::println);
        try {
            // write update to .owl ontology file
            _ontology.saveOntology();
        } catch (OWLOntologyStorageException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Statement successfully executed.");
    }

    // adds a new Individual to existing pizza.owl ontology
    public void addItemToOntology() {
        String toolName = "Sweden";
        String title = "DescribingTheTitle";
        String description = "DescribingTheIndividual";
        String parentitem = "Country";

        //check if tool exists in current ontology, otherwise delete it
        String deleteclause = "";

        // SPARQL Query:
        String _query = "PREFIX rdf:     <" + _prefixRDF + "> \n" + "PREFIX owl:     <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>\n"
                + "PREFIX ex:      <" + _prefixEX + "> \n" + deleteclause + "INSERT {ex:" + toolName + " ex:title \""
                + title + "\" ;" + "ex:description \"" + description + "\" ;" + "rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual; rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource=\"#Country\";"
                + "  .  }\n" + "WHERE { }";

        System.out.println("QUERY: " + _query);
        // parse and execute SPARQL query
        execSPARQLquery(_query);

    }

}
```

Currently my SPARQL looks like this and works:

```
PREFIX rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
PREFIX owl:     <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX ex:      <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#> 
INSERT {ex:Sweden ex:title "DescribingTheTitle" ;ex:description "DescribingTheIndividual" ;rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual;  .  }
WHERE { }
```

Protégé recognized the insertion and shows this after executing the statement. Unfortunately the font is not in bold as the other Individuals are, since there is not subclass relation, e.g.:

> Protégé (IST)
>   [image: Protege_NOW]

How do I consider subclass relationships in my SPARQL, so afterwords the ontology can look like this in Protégé?

> Protégé (SOLL)
>   [image: Protege_NTH]

I have also tried to put something like

```java
rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource=\"#Country\"
```

into my INSERT clause. When doing so,  I am only getting the following exception:

```java
org.apache.jena.query.QueryException: Line 4, column 122: Unresolved prefixed name: rdfs:subClassOf
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.lang.ParserSPARQL11Update._parse(ParserSPARQL11Update.java:75)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.lang.ParserSPARQL11Update.parse$(ParserSPARQL11Update.java:40)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.lang.UpdateParser.parse(UpdateParser.java:39)
    at org.apache.jena.update.UpdateFactory.make(UpdateFactory.java:87)
    at org.apache.jena.update.UpdateFactory.create(UpdateFactory.java:78)
    at org.apache.jena.update.UpdateFactory.create(UpdateFactory.java:56)
    at org.apache.jena.update.UpdateFactory.create(UpdateFactory.java:46)
    at org.apache.jena.update.UpdateAction.parseExecute(UpdateAction.java:136)
    at org.apache.jena.update.UpdateAction.parseExecute(UpdateAction.java:118)
    at org.apache.jena.update.UpdateAction.parseExecute(UpdateAction.java:109)
    at OntologyManipulator.execSPARQLquery(OntologyManipulator.java:27)
```

I've read few other questions related to SPARQL but no one seems to fits my query template, also the official SPARQL seems pretty poor concerning INSERT operations. Why?

I'll be grateful, if someone can help me understanding how subclass relations can be considered in SPARQL.

Comment: `rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource=\"#Country\" ` -> what is that? Either you use the full URI or the prefixed one. Your Java code is weird, but I guess `_ns` contains the namespace so in Java it would be `_ns + "Country"`. But as you already added a prefix declaration for it called `ex:`, why aren't you doing exactly the same like you did for Sweden? It should be `ex:Country`, so in Java `"rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual; rdfs:subClassOf ex:Country;" - it is a class and not an RDF string literal like your title or description

Comment: `Line 4, column 122: Unresolved prefixed name: rdfs:subClassOf` - the Update ( _query) does not declare PREFIX rdfs:

Comment: @AKSW Thank you for your hint. I changed the statement to: ´´´INSERT {ex:Sweden ex:title "DescribingTheTitle" ;ex:description "DescribingTheIndividual" ;rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual; rdfs:subClassOf ex:Country  .  }´´´ There is no expection thrown, but still the subclass relation does not seem be right, since Protégé is still showing the same result as before.

Comment: It still doesn't work because you were initially inserting the wrong triple. Why did you think Sweden is a subClassOf Country? It should be of type, or not? So you should do `rdf:type ex:Country` - Sweden is an individual not a class. Only classes are subclasses of other classes. Individuals are instances of classes expressed via `rdf:type` relation.